# Why do an object key without [] will not be the accepted parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code is a general toggle handler for a component state. I cant seems to figure out why the first set of code create a new key name property while the second set of code use the accepted parameter.

```
 controlToggle = (property) => {
    this.setState({property: !this.state.property})
  }
```

```
 controlToggle = (property) => {
    this.setState({[property]: !this.state.property})
  }
```

Comment: it looks like, you need a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). if not, you take the key `property` instead of the value of the variable.

Comment: In the first example, you're passing an object with the key `property` so react will set that in state; that is, a key for `'property'`. In the second, `[property]` will create a key of whatever the argument `property` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make use of `[]` while setting or getting a dynamic object key. If you do not provide the key within `[]` it will use the variable name as the key within the object which in your case is `property`

So for instance

```
controlToggle = (property) => {
    this.setState({property: !this.state.property})
}
```

The above code will set the state with key as `property`

While the correct way is

```
controlToggle = (property) => {
    this.setState({[property]: !this.state[property]})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because in `JavaScript`, for a key-value pair like `{XXX: YYY}`, it will automatically treat the first `XXX` as the key/property name of the value, so you have to add the [] brackets to "escape" that pattern to use the variable's value as the key instead of treating it as a string essentially.

More specifically, the stuff inside the [] brackets will be treated as normal JavaScript code and be "[calculated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)"